# How to get rid of iPhone pointer uint8_t warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, ffmpeg

I'm using **FFMPeg** on my iPhone project, but I'm getting a warning when using `AVFrame *pFrame`,  like this:

```
AVFrame *pFrame
uint8_t *data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];

...

pFrame->data
```

This is the warning I'm getting:

```
Passing 'uint8_t *[8]' to parameter of type 'const uint8_t *const *' (aka 'const unsigned char *const *') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to the type the function is expecting:

`(const uint8_t *const *)(pFrame->data)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked great and I didn't have to change the FFMPeg source code :-)

Answer (score 2):

change to

```
const uint8_t *data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
```

Comment: (const uint8_t *const *)(pFrame->data) worked better, so I don't have to change the FFMPeg source code. Thanks for your answer!